# ¿Cómo unir datos y convertir en xml?

Tags: php, xml

Obtengo los datos de un archivo`xml` de la siguiente manera:

```
$fileXML = file_get_contents('Documents/file.xml');
$xmlfile = loadXML($fileXML);
```

Para no hacer extensa la pregunta está ya pasa por otros procesos para tener de esto:

```
<factura>
    <infofactura>data...</infofactura>
    <detalles>data...</detalles>
</factura>
```

A esto:

```
<factura><infofactura>data...</infofactura><detalles>data...</detalles></factura>
```

Ahora yo tengo información en unas variables concatenadas:

```
$tagsXML = '';
$tagsXML .= '<otraetiquetas>'.$data.'</otraaetiquetas>';
```

Está información de esta variable `$tagsXML` la quiero insertar en la variable `$xmlfile` para tener el siguiente resultado:

```
<factura><infofactura>data...</infofactura><detalles>data...</detalles><otraetiquetas>Más datos</otraetiquetas></factura>
```

En resumen tener la unión de ambos en una variable `$Docxml` y posteriormente guardar dicha información en un archivo `.xml`.

He visto lo siguiente `str_replace` que permite reemplazar contenido pero no entiendo cómo agregar está información `$tagsXML` dentro de la etiqueta `<factura>` y la misma información que debe ir al final del cierre `</factura>` tal cómo he expuesto en los ejemplos del resultado deseado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo del siguiente modo:

1. Creas el elemento usando [`createElement()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.createelement.php)
2. Creas una referencia al nodo donde quieres insertar ese nuevo elemento, lo puedes alcanzar por su nombre de tag con [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)
3. Insertas el nuevo elemento en ese nodo con [`appendChild()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domnode.appendchild.php)
4. Finalmente, guardas el XML modificado con [`saveXML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.savexml.php) para este caso.

---

Ejemplo completo [<kbd>`VER DEMO`</kbd>](https://rextester.com/FKXSPL70782):

```
$strXML='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><data><factura><infofactura>Texto en infofactura</infofactura><detalles>Texto en detalles</detalles></factura></data>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($strXML);
$element = $dom->createElement('nuevaEtiqueta', 'Nuevos datos');
$facturas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('factura');
$facturas->item(0)->appendChild($element);
$dom->saveXML();
foreach ($facturas as $factura) {
    foreach ($factura->childNodes as $node){
        printf("%s: %s\n",$node->tagName,$node->nodeValue);
   }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
infofactura: Texto en infofactura
detalles: Texto en detalles
nuevaEtiqueta: Nuevos datos
```